# Attach metadata to token with metaplex

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, metadata, mint

I am trying to attach metadata uploaded to arweave to a token. I am using `createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction` from @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata, but I am getting an error.

This is the fc

```
createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction(
      {
        metadata: pda,
        mint: mintKeypair.publicKey,
        mintAuthority: mintAuthority,
        payer: payer.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: mintAuthority,
      },
      {
        createMetadataAccountArgsV3: {
          data: ON_CHAIN_METADATA,
          isMutable: true,
          collectionDetails: null,
        },
      }
    )
```

what I am unsure of

1. where to get pda? All I'm doing rn is
   `const pda = await metaplex.nfts().pdas().metadata({ mint: wallet.publicKey });` but I am not sure this is the correct way
2. what is  `collectionDetails: null`? I put null because I do not know

ERROR I am getting:

```
'Program log: IX: Create Metadata Accounts v3',
    "Program log: panicked at 'range end index 36 out of range for slice of length 0', library/core/src/slice/index.rs:73:5",
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 7998 of 972240 compute units',
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `wallet.publicKey`, you should be using the mint address of the token you're trying to create a metadata account for. The address of the metadata account is derived using the token mint address.

```
const pda = await metaplex.nfts().pdas().metadata({ mint: TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS })
```

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview#nfts

[image]

`collectionDetails` is only used for NFTs to specify a "collection nft". Its correct to leave as null if you are creating the metadata account for a fungible token. You can read more about metaplex collections from their docs.

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections#collection-nfts

[image]

Also, the `data` for `createMetadataAccountArgsV3` should be in the format of the `DataV2` type from `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata`

For example:

```
const ON_CHAIN_METADATA= {
  name: "Token Name",
  symbol: "SYMBOL",
  uri: uri, // this is the uri to the offchain metadata
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
  creators: null,
  collection: null,
  uses: null,
} as DataV2
```

```
createMetadataAccountArgsV3: {
  data: ON_CHAIN_METADATA,
  isMutable: true,
  collectionDetails: null,
}
```

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview#a-json-standard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have both mint authority and freeze authority set if it's first time to attach metadata to your mint.

Metadata program now enforces to check both mint authority and freeze authority.